# How to download lynda.com videos for offline use

Tags: video, download, download-manager, offline-files

I have access to the full library of lynda.com in the university. I would like to know how I could download the videos so that I can watch them at home.
As a tip: If I send the link of the video with the help of "Internet Download Manager" I can watch the same video without being in the network of the university! But it has to be done for each and every video. How can I do this for all the small and big videos on the page in one tutorial?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to their [FAQ](http://www.lynda.com/support/faq.aspx):

> **How can I download courses for offline viewing?**
>
> Annual Premium members can download courses on iOS app or Android app to watch offline where Internet connection is not available.

> **Which lynda.com members can download courses?**
>
> The offline viewing feature is available to annual premium members, as well as all lyndaCampus, lyndaEnterprise, and lyndaPro users.